# postgres JSONB: check if all keys *contained by* an array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

the [postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) says that i can use `?&` to check if a JSONB object's keys *contains* all elements in an array. is there something for me to check if all keys in an JSONB objects are *contained by* a given array?

so doing a query like

```
select my_jsonb_column 
from my_table
where my_jsonb_column *contained_by* array['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

would yield results as the following where the keys are a *subset* of the given array.

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Hint: `array(select jsonb_object_keys(my_jsonb_column))` and [Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply! so i posted a solution based on your suggestion and it works, but i don't understand why it's necessary to have `select` inside the `array` function. apparently it doesn't work without it. would be great if you can point me to some resources for an explanation. thanks!

Comment: `array()` here is not regular function but [Array Constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS). IMO It is not necessary to have two separate forms of constructor for subquery and for [SRF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) results.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to @abelisto's suggestion, i came up with this and it seems to work

```
select *
from my_table
where array(select jsonb_object_keys(my_json_column)) <@ array['a', 'b', 'c'];
```